# How to install Epoccam on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

How to install EPoccam on ubuntu 20.04? It is only for Mac and Win.
Bye :)

Comment: https://github.com/ohwgiles/epoccam_linux

Comment: I can't run it :(

Comment: Why not?  How far did you get? At what point did the results of a command not produce the expected results, you should provide details in your question.

Comment: after starting the program, an icon appears on the top bar. nothing happens. the only option is quit

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: You can use Droidcan instead. It is actively developed, and it does the same job. https://github.com/aramg/droidcam/

Comment: I have Nokia 808 with Symbian :( And DroidCam is not working for Symbian

Comment: Only Epoccam/Smartcam/Mobiola Web cam